# How to update values in table

Tags: php, sql

I cannot update the values in my table with this code, if the update is successful the page should redirect in ('Location:ui.php'), how can this be achieved?

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('dbconnect.php');

$code=$_GET['stallcode'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $pcost = $_POST['pcost'];
    $tcost = $_POST['tcost'];
    $cash = $_POST['cash'];
    $change = $_POST['change'];
    if (($cash == '0')) 
    {
        $pstatus="0";
    }
    else
    {
        $pstatus="1";
    }

    $updated=mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_stallowner SET 
            paymentstatus='$pstatus', penaltycost='$pcost',        totalcost='$tcost', cash='$cash', change='$change' 
            WHERE stallcode='$code'")or die();
    if($updated)
    {
        $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
        header('Location:ui.php');
    }
}  //update ends here

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: What happens? Error messages? You should escape your posted values and not use the deprecated mysql functions.

Answer (score 0):

As you redirects users by checking `if($updated)` is true, this will not work, you should check the number of affected rows instead using `mysql_num_rows`.

Also remember to `exit;` after `header()` to stop the execution.

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($updated);
if($num_rows > 0)
{
$msg="Successfully Updated!!";
header('Location:ui.php');
exit;
}
```

**Tip**: You should not be using `MySQL` as it has already been deprecated, use `MySQLi` instead.

Comment: This answer will work however you shouldn't use this as a fix but instead move to MySQLi as luweiqi points out.

Comment: Hi @Enzo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use mysqli, not it's predecessor, mysql. Mysql is vulnerable and open to exploitation, here's what you should write in each of your files:

> dbconnect.php

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

> updatestallowner.php (or whatever you named it)

```
<?php
ob_start();
require('dbconnect.php');
$code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['stallcode']);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $pcost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pcost']);
    $tcost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tcost']);
    $cash = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cash']);
    $change = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['change']);
    if ($cash == '0') {
        $pstatus="0";
    } else{
        $pstatus="1";
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_stallowner SET paymentstatus='$pstatus', penaltycost='$pcost', totalcost='$tcost', cash='$cash', change='$change' WHERE stallcode='$code';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result) {
        $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
        header('Location: ui.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        die("Error updating!");
    }
}

?>
```

Good luck!